# set Roman and Arabic page numbering in book class

Tags: page-numbering, arabic, page, roman

How do you make a roman numbering appear in the middle of the bottom of some pages, while Arabic numbering appears in the lower right of later pages in one document?

Comment: You want *two* page numbers on the same page? (!)

Comment: No. I want to make some page. In the beginning, use roman numbering, and afer that using arabic numbering. where the roman in the middle and the arabic in right side.

Comment: You can define two different page styles, say `footera` and `footerb`, and then use `\pagestyle{footera|` and `\pagestyle{footerb}` as appropriate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton how to define it?